# Reshape a video element in HTML/CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to show a video in a HTML/CSS/JS prototype, no problem.
Now the trick is that on the design, the video is shaped like a circle.
Placing the controls will be a challenge but my question is;
Is it posible to display a video shaped like a circle in HTML, CSS or JS?

Thanks in advance!

PS: support is not very important as it is for a prototype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This post attempts to answer the same question using CSS3 rounded corners.  You will just need to make your radii half of the length & width to get a perfect circle:

[rounded corners on html5 video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6238451/rounded-corners-on-html5-video)

Comment: If it was so simple I would not have asked the question. I can try to add this css to the video element but the video itself will not be reshaped.

Comment: I tried the solution at the above link and it works, I made a video shaped like a circle using this CSS mask and SVG file: -webkit-mask-image: url(http://f.cl.ly/items/1e181Q0e3j0L3L3z2j3Z/rect.svg)

Comment: . . . exactly like the post says.